# Two parameters to a C# thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I can send one parameter in the thread

```
class myThread
{
    Thread thread;
    public myThread(string name, int st)
    {
        thread = new Thread(this.Get_IP);
        thread.Name = name;
        thread.Start(st);//передача параметра в поток
        thread.Join();
    }
    void Get_IP(object st)
    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < (int)st; ii++)
        {
            // smth
        }
    }
}
```

But i need to send two of them
for example

```
for (int ii = (int)st; ii < (int)fi; ii++)
{
    // smth
}
```

there is a way to put 2 params all together

```
void A(int a, int b) { }
```

and

```
ThreadStart starter = delegate { A(0, 10); };
```

But how can i send them to the thread?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the Task Parallel Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the two variables as members in the class:

```
class MyThread {

  private Thread _thread;
  private int _start, _finish;

  public MyThread(string name, int start, int finish) {

    _start = start;
    _finish = finish;

    _thread = new Thread(Get_IP);
    _thread.Name = name;
    _thread.Start();
    _thread.Join();
  }

  void Get_IP() {
    for (int ii = _start; ii < _finish; ii++) {
      // smth
    }
  }

}
```

Note: Calling `Join` right after starting the thread makes is pretty pointless to use a thread.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass more parameters to thread by using lambda expresion. Like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(()=>A(5,6));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Thread.Start` method accepts an `object` as parameter. You can pass an array of your values.

```
thread.Start(new object[] { a, b });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that hold all of the values you need to pass and pass an instance of that class to your thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send 2 parametes, you can send them as any type you like, but in the method that starts new thread, you have to unbox it/them:

```
    void MyMethod()
    {           
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int[] data = new[] { a, b };
        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(StartThread));
        t.Start(data);
    }

    private void StartThread(object obj)
    {
        int[] data = obj as int[];
        if (data != null)
        {
            int a = data[0];
            int b = data[1];
        }
    }
```

NOTE: method that is called by new Thread can only accppt object parameter. What is inside this object is not code`s concern, can be anything, like I boxes 2 integers.
Then you simply unbox the object to your original data types.